# Reading name and occupation of 18th century ancestors from Kirchheim unter Teck, Württemberg, Germany?

Tags: germany, 18th-century, palaeography, baden-wuerttemberg

Here is the family record of one my ancestors, Tobias Brackenhammer, Coachmann (germ. *Kutscher*) and Ana Maria Gollmar from Kirchheim unter Teck, Württemberg, Germany.

Below the name of the couple is written the name and occupation of all 4 grandparents. On the left there is Jacob Brackenhamer, farmer (germ. *Bauer*) and Magdalena Barbara born Harsch.

The problem is that I cannot read exactly what is on the right. There is Jacob Gollmar, but I cannot read his occupation. The grandma appears to be also named Ana Maria, but I cannot read her birth family name.

[image]

Can you help me to read the grandpa's occupation and the grandma's birth name? (click on the image to enlarge)

For some reason whoever hold those register liked to decline names in feminine with the -in suffix (in this case *Gollmarin*, *Harschin*), but this is never done in modern german language so I belive those should be ignored.

Comment: I just uploaded a picture of *slightly* better quality.

Comment: I am from Kirchheim/Teck (Germany). The mentioned names in your question are all my ancestors. I can give you a complete draft of all descendants beginning by Tobias Br. Perhaps you can use my user profile to contact me so that I can send you an image of the family tree.

Comment: @DieterBrackenhammer Welcome to G&FH SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format which is quite different from bulletin boards, discussion forums and other Q&A sites you may be used to.  It is fine to include your contact details in your [user profile](http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/users/5772/dieter-brackenhammer?tab=profile) but they must not appear in any posts (questions, answers and comments).  You can use a comment to direct a user to your user profile but such comments are temporary and can be deleted at any time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]As a descendant of Tobias Brackenhammer (my great-great-great-grandfather), I can confirm the following personal data:

- Tobias Brackenhammer (13.06.1780 in Gechingen near Calw - 04.10.1840 in Kirchheim / Teck) by profession Kutscher, day laborer and peasant - marriage 1810 in Gechingen Anna Maria Gollmar (25.02.1783 in Oberlenningen - 24.12.1872 Kirchheim / T. Former Gollmarin = female form)
- Johann Jacob Brackenhammer (25.03.1733 in Gechingen b Calw - 02.06.1804 in Gechingen) by profession Bauer and baker with Mrs. Margaretha Magdalena Harsch (1745 - 1799 Gechingen)
- Jacob Gollmar (1744 - 1820) from Oberlenningen near Kirchheim / T. By profession Schneider with Mrs. Barbara Sailer from Oberlenningen (1755 - 1820)

The above is Google translated from the original text which appears below:

> Als Nachfahre von Tobias Brackenhammer (my
>   great-great-great-grandfather) kann ich folgende Personendaten
>   bestätigen:
>
> - Tobias Brackenhammer (13.06.1780 in Gechingen bei Calw - 04.10.1840 in Kirchheim/Teck) von Beruf Kutscher, Taglöhner und Bauer - Heirat
>     1810 in Gechingen Anna Maria Gollmar (25.02.1783 in Oberlenningen -
>     24.12.1872 Kirchheim/T. (früher Gollmarin = weibl. Form)
> - Johann Jacob Brackenhammer (25.03.1733 in Gechingen b. Calw - 02.06.1804 in Gechingen) von Beruf Bauer u. Bäcker mit Frau Margaretha Magdalena Harsch(in) (1745 - 1799 Gechingen)
> - Jacob Gollmar (1744 - 1820) aus Oberlenningen bei Kirchheim/T. von Beruf Schneider mit Frau Barbara Sailer aus Oberlenningen (1755 -
>     1820)

Comment: Hallo, sind Sie meinen entfernen Cousin ? Das klingt etwas interessant ! Was ist Ihre Source nach Ihre informationen ? Ich hoffe, dass wir wieder Kontakte haben können.

Comment: Comment by @Bregalad translates via Google to "Hello, are you removing my cousin? That sounds interesting! What is your source for your information? I hope we can have contacts again."

Comment: Hallo @Bregalad certainly we are distant cousins. I add the pedigree to my answer believing it suits to your family line. More information later.

Comment: @PolyGeo Why do you use Google as a tool to translate between German and English language ? Google is horrible at translating between language, and there is plenty of people who speaks both (me, for instance - although I speak both poorly)

Comment: @Bregalad G&FH SE is an English language site.  I don't speak German and Google Translate is the quickest way that I can bring any part of content written in languages other than English (LOTE) to that.  It saves each of us having to open up Google Translate and do the same.  For background on using LOTE here see http://meta.genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/1888/what-should-our-policy-be-on-qa-in-language-other-than-english-lote

Comment: Are you sure about the reading of that last name? I would have read this as "Gollmer", which is a more common last name, and the writing agrees with the way the column headings "Hausvater" and "Hausmutter" are rendered.

Comment: @user3697176 There's no doubt the last name ist Gollmar respectively Gollmarin (a former female version). But you're right in Germany there is a similar family name Gollmer also common.

Answer (score 4):

Interesting that the scribe added the suffix "-in" to all the maiden names. Latin for "origin" or "coming from".

Tobias Brackenhammer, son of Jacob Brackenhammer and Margaretha Magdalena born Harsch(in).

Ana Maria Gollmar(in), daughter of Jacob Gollmar and Ana Maria born Sailer(in).

Can't read the occupation, do you have a better scan? Maybe Seifensieder? (Soap maker)

Here is a document from the week before (marriage bond? license?) https://familysearch.org/ark:/61903/1:1:N88C-Y1T  No image available, but index reads:

Tobias Brockenhammer, son of Johann Jakob Brockenhammer.

Ana Maria Gollmar, daughter of Jakob Gollmar and Barbara Sailer.

Comment: *Barbara* Sailer ?! They definitely screwed it up.

Comment: Well, don't jump to conclusions. She could be Ana Maria Barbara Sailer.

Comment: I just uploaded pictures of slightly better quality. Also, I believe suppositions like *she could be* are not helpful, as we can basically reinvent our ancestors as we'd like taking this route.

Comment: Not reinventing anyone, just letting you know that it was common for Germans to be given at least three Christian names at baptism, if not more. And often the second or third is their common everyday name, but not their formal name. Don't discount any Barbara's you come across, until you have more documentation.

Comment: Your logic doesn't sound right to me. Of course it wasn't uncommon to have 3 names, but 2 names was the most common case. So you should not assume that she had 3 names. I do not know if the *more documentation* you're talking about exist at all, and even if it does I'm not likely to ever get my hands on it.

Comment: I'm not assuming anything, simply not dismissing anything either. Do you have evidence implying one document is more correct than the other? Familysearch has lots of records for this town. Have you researched all the BMD's of the wives and children of Jacob Gollmar?

Comment: I tried to, but the FamilySearch's interface is so weird that it ended up not doing what I wanted it to do and bind it with another unrelated family and, well I just couldn't cancel that binding. I don't remember if I had that problem with that branch or another in the family, but anyway, you see the problem with FamilySeach. Anyway, it's no problem as I know enough for that family as I'd have liked to.

Answer (score 3):

After the occupation (and a couple of other times on the page) the grandfather is listed as working in Oberboihingen which is the town just west of Kirchheim unter teck. You could try looking there for other records too if you haven't already.

As for the occupation, a higher resolution scan would be needed and even then it would be very hard, I'll have another go at it and edit this if I can help at all further.

Personally I think the occupation starts with an I or a J. But I can't find anything that fits well.

Answer (score 2):

Jacob Gollmar's occupation *may* be "Schneider" meaning [Tailor](http://www.jewishgen.org/InfoFiles/GermanOccs.htm). The ending doesn't quite look like -der, but the word does start with Sch- and the middle has the right length and heights for -nei-. Also you've previously mentioned family occupations related to clothing manufacture, and a tailor fits in that group.

Comment: Maybe... There is two whole generations between my great-great-grandmother which was *schneider* and Jacob Gollmar (namely, August Hermann Brackenhammer *Kübler* and Tobias Brackenhammer *Kutscher*) so if both had the same job it should have been mostly by coincidence